# cucumber scenario with more than one tags

Tags: cucumber

Is it possible to add more than one tag to a cucumber scenario?

For example, I have a test which I need to include in smoke test as well as regression tests. When I add 2 tags to the scenario, it is getting skipped

Comment: U can add as many tags as u want to scenarios in a feature file. Need to be separated by a comma. Can u add the relevant featurr and cucumberoptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple tags. For more information, see the [Cucumber documentation](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tags)